# Error when running tensorflow and matplotlib

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow, but when i run my code i get a huge error and dont know how to fix it. I also get and error about my gpu not being used, but i have updated CUDA, downloaded cuDNN and upgraded my gpu but nothing works.

my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

i get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Christian Egelund\OneDrive\Skrivebord\c++ A Beginners Guide\Machine Learning> python -u "c:\Users\Christian Egelund\OneDrive\Skrivebord\c++ A Beginners Guide\Machine Learning\first.py"
2021-04-14 22:55:05.015121: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-04-14 22:55:05.025996: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Christian Egelund\OneDrive\Skrivebord\c++ A Beginners Guide\Machine Learning\first.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
  File "C:\Users\Christian Egelund\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Christian Egelund\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "C:\Users\Christian Egelund\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "C:\Users\Christian Egelund\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional
  File "C:\Users\Christian Egelund\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 38, in <module> 
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training as training_lib
  File "C:\Users\Christian Egelund\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 52, in <module>   
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import data_adapter
  File "C:\Users\Christian Egelund\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 61, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse as scipy_sparse  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
  File "C:\Users\Christian Egelund\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Christian Egelund\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Det angivne modul blev ikke fundet
PS C:\Users\Christian Egelund\OneDrive\Skrivebord\c++ A Beginners Guide\Machine Learning>
```

Comment: lease notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should *not* be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out). It should also be obvious that the error has nothing to do with Matplotlib.

Comment: @Egelund48, Can you let us know steps that you have followed to install Tensorflow and version details of TF, CUDA, cuDNN? Complete code to replicate your issue, so that we can try to help you. Thanks!